# how to go back and forth in the view stack in vi

Tags: buffers, the-silver-searcher

I'm not sure if I'm asking this right (I think this is a buffer thing?) so here is the scenario (in [gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin))
As a vim user, i would like to use the silver searcher to search for files which have keywords and be able to go back and forth between the files i have visted:

**given** user launched vi
**and** user searched for a term using silver searcher
**and** search results appeared in the quick help window
[image]
**and** user selected one of the files
**and** that file loaded

question: how can the user *go back* to the original file that was already loaded *before* they jumped to the new file? and supposing they did go back, how can they go forward back to the file they just searched?

Comment: what's so bad about the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Jumplist

You can use `<c-o>` / `<c-i>` to travel back and forward through the jump list. You can see the jump list via `:jumps`. However this my not be the fastest way to get back as you may have jumped a few times.

#### Alternative file

You can use `<c-6>` / `<c-^>` / `:b #` to switch to the alternative buffer. This is typically the previous buffer. You can see which buffer is the alternate buffer by looking for the buffer marked with `#` in the buffer list via: `:ls` / `:buffers`

This only works if the previous buffer is the one you want to go to or if you know the buffer number you want to go to (e.g. `5<c-6>`).

#### Use file marks

You can set an upper case mark (file marks) which will allow you to jump between files. Simply set it before you search `mM`, then after you search jump via `'M`.

The downside with this is you must set the mark before you do your searching.

#### Splits

If you know you are going go back to your original buffer use a split to view your search result (maybe via `<c-w><cr>` in the quickfix window) and keep your original buffer open. That way all you need to do is close your search buffer (possibly the quickfix window as well, `:cclose`).

Once again this requires you to know in advance that you will be going back.

#### Advanced buffer navigation

You can use `:b` to directly jump to the buffer you desire. Use `:b {partial-file-name}` to jump back. You can also use tab completion (`<c-d>` to list completions) and globs (e.g. `:b **/foo*.bar`).

A common mapping for buffer navigation:

```
nnoremap <leader>b :ls<cr>:b<space>
```

#### For more help see

```
:h jump-motions
:h alternative-file
:h mark-motions
:h :b
:h :ls
:h CTRL-6
:h c_CTRL-D
:h cmdline-completion
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:bpre` and `:bnext` to go to previous buffer and next one.

Comment: How can I view/list all the open buffers?

Comment: `:buffers` will help. `:h buffers` for more.